How do I combine AudioKit and ARKit
I have a situation where I want to

Detect objects using ARKit ✅
Synthesise audio using AudioKit ✅
Pipe the generated audio to the SCNNode

First step, set up AudioKit
    func initKit() {
        // set up the audio engine
        do {
            try audioSession.setCategory(.playback)
            try audioSession.setActive(true)
            print("Started audio session")
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        
        do {
            try engine.start()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

Then detect the objects in the scene with the camera:
    func rendererDidAdd(node: SCNNode, planeAnchor: ARPlaneAnchor) {
        // save the node so we can remove the planes later
        sceneNodes.insert(node)
        // Create a custom object to visualize the plane geometry and extent.
        let plane = Plane(anchor: planeAnchor, in: arView, attachedNode: node)
        // store the planes for access later
        planes.append(plane)
        
        // filter out unwanted planes
        switch planeAnchor.classification {

        ...

        default:
            // table, seat, window, door
            addNoiseFor(node: node, plane: plane)
            // add the plane to view if applicable
            addPlaneToView(node: node, plane: plane, planeAnchor: planeAnchor)
        }
        
    }

Then add the noise to the node and start it.
    func addNoiseFor(node: SCNNode, plane: Plane) {
        let pink = PinkNoise(amplitude: 0.5)
        
        let player = SCNAudioPlayer(avAudioNode: pink.avAudioNode)
        player.willStartPlayback = {
            print("Started playing")
        }
        node.addAudioPlayer(player)
        pink.start()
        
        print("Playing audio for \(plane.identifier)")
    }

I have also tried creating a custom AVAudioSourceNode (generator)

struct OptionNames {
    static let signal = "signal"
    static let frequency = "freq"
    static let duration = "duration"
    static let output = "output"
    static let amplitude = "amplitude"
}

let getFloatForKeyOrDefault = { (key: String, defaultValue: Float) -> Float in
    let value = UserDefaults.standard.float(forKey: key)
    return value > 0.0 ? value : defaultValue
}

    let frequency = getFloatForKeyOrDefault(OptionNames.frequency, 440)
    let amplitude = min(max(getFloatForKeyOrDefault(OptionNames.amplitude, 0.5), 0.0), 1.0)
    let duration = getFloatForKeyOrDefault(OptionNames.duration, 5.0)
    let outputPath = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: OptionNames.output)
    var currentPhase: Float = 0
    let twoPi = 2 * Float.pi
    // The interval to advance the phase each frame.
    let phaseIncrement = (Float.pi * 2 / 48000) * 440
    
[...]

    func addNoiseFor(node: SCNNode, plane: Plane) {
        
        let srcNode = AVAudioSourceNode { _, _, frameCount, audioBufferList -> OSStatus in
            let ablPointer = UnsafeMutableAudioBufferListPointer(audioBufferList)
            for frame in 0..<Int(frameCount) {
                // Get the signal value for this frame at time.
                let value = self.currentPhase * self.amplitude
                // Advance the phase for the next frame.
                self.currentPhase += self.phaseIncrement
                if self.currentPhase >= self.twoPi {
                    self.currentPhase -= self.twoPi
                }
                if self.currentPhase < 0.0 {
                    self.currentPhase += self.twoPi
                }
                // Set the same value on all channels (due to the inputFormat, there's only one channel though).
                for buffer in ablPointer {
                    let buf: UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Float> = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(buffer)
                    buf[frame] = value
                }
            }
            return noErr
        }
        
        // let player = SCNAudioPlayer(avAudioNode: pink.avAudioNode)
        let player = SCNAudioPlayer(avAudioNode: srcNode)
        player.willStartPlayback = {
            print("Started playing")
        }
        node.addAudioPlayer(player)
        
        print("Playing audio for \(plane.identifier)")
    }

However, this doesn't work because pink is expecting an AVAudioEngine instance attached to the AVAudioNode, and SCNNode doesn't create one. In fact, when using  SCNAudioPlayer(avAudioNode:) it doesn't appear to attach one at any point.
It also never calls back to willStartPlayback().
Now, I did a bit of investigation and ARKit does attach an AVAudioEngine instance as soon as it renders, which can be checked by the callback:
func renderer(_ renderer: any SCNSceneRenderer, didRenderScene scene: SCNScene, atTime time: TimeInterval) {}
…and it will also play audio back if instead of attaching SCNAudioPlayer(avAudioNode:) you attach an audio file player with SCNAudioSource(fileNamed:) (what confusing naming conventions). Whereby it seems to do some internal initialisation that doesn't happen with the avAudioNode version.
The crux of the matter is that I don't know how you should set up the SCNAudioPlayer(avAudioNode:) in order to 'start' the audio. There's definitely something missing! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Working with the AV Framwork (AVFoundation / Audio Engine) requires different approach as using some SCNAudio. The Advantage of SCNAudio: It's setup is quite quick and easy, but it is not that much customisable compared to things you can do using the Audio Engine. If you want to play "quick" Sound Effects, that belongs to SCNNodes, you could simply use SCNAction.playAudio... it requires a SCNAudioSource. The setup is easy. And then you run the Action on the Node whenever you want.

UsingSCNAction.playAudio still requires you to use an SCNAudioSource. If you can call node.addAudioPlayer(avAudioNode:) with an AVAudioNode instance, what is the use case?

Here is an Example of how to play Sound using SCNAudioNode:
import UIKit
import QuartzCore
import SceneKit
import AVFoundation

class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var sceneView = SCNView()
    let gameScene = SCNScene()
    
    let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
    let audioPlayerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // create and add a camera to the scene
        let cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        gameScene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
        
        // place the camera
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 15)
        
        // create and add a light to the scene
        let lightNode = SCNNode()
        lightNode.light = SCNLight()
        lightNode.light!.type = .omni
        lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 10, z: 10)
        gameScene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)
        
        // create and add an ambient light to the scene
        let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
        ambientLightNode.light = SCNLight()
        ambientLightNode.light!.type = .ambient
        ambientLightNode.light!.color = UIColor.darkGray
        gameScene.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)
        
        sceneView = self.view as! SCNView
        
        // set the scene to the view
        sceneView.scene = gameScene
        
        // allows the user to manipulate the camera
        sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
        
        // show statistics such as fps and timing information
        sceneView.showsStatistics = false
        
        // configure the view
        sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        
        // add a tap gesture recognizer
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_:)))
        sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        
        self.setupAudioEngine()
        
    }
    
    func setupAudioEngine() {
        
        audioEngine.attach(audioPlayerNode)
        // Load your audio file into an AVAudioPCMBuffer
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "art.scnassets/some_sound", withExtension: "mp3") else {
            fatalError("Audio file not found")
        }
        let audioFile = try! AVAudioFile(forReading: url)
        let audioFormat = audioFile.processingFormat
        let audioFrameCount = UInt32(audioFile.length)
        let audioBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: audioFormat, frameCapacity: audioFrameCount)!
        try! audioFile.read(into: audioBuffer)

        audioEngine.connect(audioPlayerNode, to: audioEngine.outputNode, format: audioBuffer.format)

        try! audioEngine.start()

        // audioPlayerNode.scheduleBuffer(audioBuffer, at: nil, options: .loops, completionHandler: nil) // Looping
        audioPlayerNode.scheduleBuffer(audioBuffer, at: nil, options: [], completionHandler: nil) // No Looping

        
    }
    
    func setupNode() {
        
        let node = SCNNode(geometry: SCNSphere(radius: 1.0))
        
        let material = SCNMaterial()
        material.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
        material.lightingModel = .physicallyBased
        
        node.geometry?.firstMaterial = material
        
        gameScene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
        
        // Create an SCNAudioPlayer using the AVAudioNode
        let scnAudioPlayer = SCNAudioPlayer(avAudioNode: audioPlayerNode)
        node.addAudioPlayer(scnAudioPlayer)
        
        // Play the audio
        audioPlayerNode.play()
        
    }
    
    @objc func handleTap(_ gestureRecognize: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        self.setupNode()
    }
    
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            return .allButUpsideDown
        } else {
            return .all
        }
    }

}

Add a sound File to your Project (adjust naming accordingly)
Run the App and tap the screen. (turn sound on)

Thanks, but I'm not looking to play an audio file. I want to generate audio using AudioKit and attach that node, and have it spatialised using the in-built SceneKit AVAudioEngine. It has an internal audio spatialisation workflow to do this which you can hook into, and which works using SCNAudioSource, but which should also work using SCNAudioPlayer. Yours works because you're attaching it to your own engine, and also calling play on it. It's essentially outside of the SCNNode audio ecosystem.

okay, so you want to create/generate audio, like a sine-wave or some noise using the AudioEngine, and add some filtering/effects to it?

Yes, exactly. See the example I put above into the question with AVAudioSourceNode.

Do you probably mean a AVAudioEnvironmentNode() ? And Playback the generated Audio using SCNAudioPlayer?

AVAudioSourceNode should work as a manual audio renderer attached to another node. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/audio_engine/building_a_signal_generator . AVAudioEnvironmentNode would also duplicate the functionality that ARKit's providing by setting additional spatialisation.
